# What does @ and ~ mean at the bottom?

Tags: vim

When I'm editing plain text files (not any code files), sometime I see signs like @ and ~ at the bottom in different colors as I scroll, and sometimes they disappear. What do they mean in vim?

Comment: `~` could be the beginning of line in vim thats just a place holder to say that line isn't in the file. (to differentiate from blank lines that are in the file) Could you post a screen shot? As I'm not sure if were even talking about the same thing.

Comment: It is possible to get rid of the `@@@@`'s by adding `set display+=lastline` in your `.vimrc`.  This tells vim to display as much of the last line as possible even if it gets cut off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @ sign appears at the bottom when you have a really long line of code (or text) that continues (wraps) to the next line.

the ~ sign is just a place holder that says nothing is on that line (not even spaces or tabs or returns)